# space in a select statement in dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a dynamic query like this :

```
SET @str_Query = 'SELECT SIM.Item_ID,
                  SIM.Item_Description,
                  SU.Short_Description AS Unit,
                  SIM.Std_Lead_Time,'+
                  '' ''+' AS Last_Purchase_Rate
                  FROM  FKMS_Item_Master AS SIM
                        INNER JOIN FKMS_STP_Units SU
                        ON SIM.Item_Purchase_Unit=SU.Unit_Id' +
                 ' WHERE ' + @str_Condition + 
                            ' AND SIM.Location_Id =' + CAST(@aint_Location_Id AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' AND SIM.Item_Deleted =0 
                              AND SIM.Approved_On IS NOT NULL'  
                +' ORDER BY SIM.Item_Description'
```

I want to retrieve space as Last_Purchase_Rate

It is showing syntax error in the portion of '' ''+' AS Last_Purchase_Rate
when I execute this query.
If I print this dynamic query, query seems correct. It shows as  AS Last_Purchase_Rate with space before AS. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write

```
...SIM.Std_Lead_Time, '' '' AS Last_Purchase_Rate...
```

instead of

```
...SIM.Std_Lead_Time,'+'' ''+' AS Last_Purchase_Rate...
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not escape all quotes.

A working version of your statement would be

```
SET @str_Query = 'SELECT SIM.Item_ID,
                  SIM.Item_Description,
                  SU.Short_Description AS Unit,
                  SIM.Std_Lead_Time,'
                  + ''' '''
                  + ' AS Last_Purchase_Rate
                  FROM  FKMS_Item_Master AS SIM
                        INNER JOIN FKMS_STP_Units SU
                        ON SIM.Item_Purchase_Unit=SU.Unit_Id' +
                 ' WHERE ' + @str_Condition + 
                            ' AND SIM.Location_Id =' + CAST(@aint_Location_Id AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                            ' AND SIM.Item_Deleted =0 
                              AND SIM.Approved_On IS NOT NULL'  
                +' ORDER BY SIM.Item_Description'
```

but I find that with a little reformatting, the error is easier to spot

```
SET @str_Query = 
    'SELECT SIM.Item_ID '
    + ', SIM.Item_Description '
    + ', SU.Short_Description AS Unit '
    + ', SIM.Std_Lead_Time '
    + ', '' ''' + ' AS Last_Purchase_Rate '
    + 'FROM  FKMS_Item_Master AS SIM '
    + '      INNER JOIN FKMS_STP_Units SU '
    + '                   ON SIM.Item_Purchase_Unit=SU.Unit_Id ' 
    + ' WHERE ' + @str_Condition 
    + '       AND SIM.Location_Id = ' + CAST(@aint_Location_Id AS VARCHAR(10)) 
    + '       AND SIM.Item_Deleted =0 '
    + '       AND SIM.Approved_On IS NOT NULL '  
    + ' ORDER BY SIM.Item_Description '
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use NULL instead of space and then handle the result in your app?

I.e.,

```
SET @str_Query = 'SELECT SIM.Item_ID,
              SIM.Item_Description,
              SU.Short_Description AS Unit,
              SIM.Std_Lead_Time,
              NULL AS Last_Purchase_Rate, -- and so on.
```

You could also use CHAR(32):

```
SET @str_Query = 'SELECT SIM.Item_ID,
              SIM.Item_Description,
              SU.Short_Description AS Unit,
              SIM.Std_Lead_Time,
              CHAR(32) AS Last_Purchase_Rate, -- and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using tsql function `SPACE(1)`